# web url validator to class level validation

Tags: c#, class, validation, webaddress

I have a simple class and corresponding properties. I would like to add some validation rules (to a web property). I want to check that the web address is valid. What are the types of conditions I would need to check for?

My thinking:
I have to require this format www.example.sometext

Should I check for valid .sometext endings (i.e. .com, .org, etc.) Problem is there are basically unlimited of these now.

So my question who would I add a validation rule on the class level to handle this?

```
public string WebAddress { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` method. It will return  true if the string was well-formed, if not it will return false.

Link to MSDN: [IsWellFormedUriString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this was a function (wrong word to describe probably). Thank you for including link to documentation!